# How to get a list of existing directories in Azure Blob Storage container using c#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a console app written using `C#` on the top of Core .NET 2.2 framework.

I am trying to the [C# library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-tools?view=azure-dotnet&tabs=windows) to get a list of all directories inside my container. It is my understanding that Azure Blob Storage does not really have directories. Instead, it creates virtual names that the blobs look like a folder inside a container within browsers like [Azure Blob Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/)

I store my files using the following code

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("foldername/filename.jpg");

await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
```

So I want to select a distinct list of the prefix aka folder names on inside my container.

So if I have the following blobs "foldername1/file1.jpg", "foldername1/file2.jpg", "foldername1/file3.jpg", and "foldername2/file1.jpg". I want to return "foldername1", "foldername2"

How can I get a list of distinct prefixes from Azure Blob Storage?

**Updated**

I tried to get the feedback from the comments below so I came up with the following code

```
public async Task<string[]> Directories(string path = null)
{
    int index = path == null ? 0 : path.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;

    BlobContinuationToken token = null;
    List<string> directories = new List<string>();
    do
    {
        BlobResultSegment blobsListingResult = await ContainerFactory.Get().ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(path ?? string.Empty, true, BlobListingDetails.None, 5000, token, null, null);
        token = blobsListingResult.ContinuationToken;
        IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobsList = blobsListingResult.Results;
        foreach (var item in blobsList)
        {
            var blobName = (item as CloudBlob).Name;
            var blobParts = blobName.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (blobParts.Length <= index)
            {
                // At this point, we know that this not a directory inside the provided path directory
                continue;
            }

            directories.Add(blobParts[index]);
        }
    }
    while (token != null);

    return directories.Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

Since I have lots of blobs in the container, this takes way too long because it would have to almost get every single block in order to get a list of the directories. Additionally, this may be very costly since I have to read every blob every time this method is called.

I essentially need the same result that I would get as running `Directory.GetDirectories(path)` if everything was running locally! **Is there a way to improve this function?**

Comment: There are no folders in Azure Blob Storage actually, they're "virtual" and call prefixes. I don't think you have an empty folder/prefix. To get all of them you might have to enumerate all blobs, collect all their prefixes and call Distinct().

Comment: You should look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795057/272109) which answers a very similar (almost identical) question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I updated my question after looking at the answer you directed me too.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this is to not treat the Blob Storage like a folder/file store. Keep the files (blobs) there, but use some other method to track your folder structure. My method of choice is a SQL database that contains my folder structure, and then a reference to a blob file in Azure. The problem with calling all this code directly in Azure is that:

a) It'll be slow
b) It'll give you unnecessary cost in the long run

You're far better off doing as I suggest, keep metadata elsewhere, and use Blob storage for what its intended for - storing blobs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can improve your solution doing a check for the type of blob item?

```
        var result = new List<string>();
        var directory = _blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(relativeFilePath);

        if (directory.Equals(null))
            return result;

        var blobs = directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null).Result;

        foreach (var item in blobs.Results)
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory)) 
            {
                result.Add(item.Uri.Segments.Last().Trim('/'));
            }
        }

        return result;
```

I didn't have too many folders so would be good to double check if the performance meets your requirements.