# Get List of all files from all folder from Azure DataLake using C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

Can we have some example to get list of all files from all folder from Azure Data Lake using .NET(C#).

we are doing in Data factory lookup activity but performance is not good.

we need to check a alternate way to get list of  file and write in log folder

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it worked for me

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("<YOUR ACCOUNT NAME>", "<YOUR CONNECTION STRING>"), true);
            var containerName = "<YOUR CONTAINER NAME>";
            var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            BlobContinuationToken token = null;

            do
            {
                var blobPrefix = "";
                var useFlatBlobListing = true;
                var blobsListingResult = container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(blobPrefix, useFlatBlobListing, BlobListingDetails.None, 500, token, null, null);
                var blobsList = blobsListingResult.Result;
                foreach (var item in blobsList.Results)
                {
                    var blobName = (item as CloudBlob).Name;
                    Console.WriteLine(blobName);
                }
            }
            while (token != null);
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

**REFERENCES**
[How to list all virtual directories and subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782166/how-to-list-all-virtual-directories-and-subdirectories-using-azure-storage-clien)