# Azure Logic app how to append list blobs to array variable?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-account

Hi I am working on azure logic app. I have below array variable. These are the mail folder path and inside I have files.

["/mycontainer/PreDesign/1e36d504-7876-41b1-89b3-83d2132fa7c4/AdditionalDocumets","/mycontainer/PreDesign/1e36d504-7876-41b1-89b3-83d2132fa7c4/TowerCalcOutPut","/mycontainer/PreDesign/1e36d504-7876-41b1-89b3-83d2132fa7c4/TowerDataSheet"]
Then I have below method to list the blobs

[image]

Here blob list is array variable as defined above. Then I have added listblobs which will loop through each path defined in array variable and lists blobs and I want to append blobs to array variable.
Here in append array variable I am able to append only blobs available inside first array element that is /containername/PreDesign/1e36d504-7876-41b1-89b3-83d2132fa7c4/AdditionalDocumets
I am not able to append blobs which are inside mycontainer/PreDesign/1e36d504-7876-41b1-89b3-83d2132fa7c4/TowerCalcOutPut","/mycontainer/PreDesign/1e36d504-7876-41b1-89b3-83d2132fa7c4/TowerDataSheet, only first element blobs I am able to append it to array variable. I am struggling to append all the blobs to array variable. Can someone help me where exactly I am missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is `/mycontainer/PreDesign/1e36d504-7876-41b1-89b3-83d2132fa7c4` your top folder AND are the three folders below the only folders underneath that main folder?

Answer (score 0):

> I am struggling to append all the blobs to array variable. Can someone help me where exactly I am missing?

Its because the flow goes into only the first folder but not all folders.

Here is one of the workaround that you can try. Like said in [How to attach multiple blobs in logic app from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71317667/how-to-attach-multiple-blobs-in-logic-app-from-different-folder/71329547#71329547) just try adding `Append to array variable` at the end of `For each 2` and you will have paths for all the blobs in your variable. Below is the screenshot of my logic app for your reference.

[image]

**output**

[image]

Here is the code view of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@variables('BlobList')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "For_each_2": {
                        "actions": {
                            "For_each_3": {
                                "actions": {
                                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                        "inputs": {
                                            "name": "BlobList",
                                            "value": "@items('For_each_3')?['Path']"
                                        },
                                        "runAfter": {},
                                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                                    }
                                },
                                "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_in_Directory')?['value']",
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Lists_blobs_in_Directory": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "Foreach"
                            },
                            "Lists_blobs_in_Directory": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "get",
                                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each_2')?['Path']))}",
                                    "queries": {
                                        "nextPageMarker": ""
                                    }
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@body('Lists_Directories_inside_Container')?['value']",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Lists_Directories_inside_Container": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    },
                    "Lists_Directories_inside_Container": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['Path']))}",
                            "queries": {
                                "nextPageMarker": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Lists_Containers_in_root_folder')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Lists_Containers_in_root_folder": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_BlobList_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "BlobList",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Lists_Containers_in_root_folder": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": false
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_BlobList_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```